# Using enum value in entity object causes Invalid column name SQL exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I am new to Entity Framework Core and trying to set up an ASP.NET Core Web API which offers basic CRUD operations, using .NET 8.

After completing the initial migration and trying out a simple GET request, the following exception gets systematically thrown:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'Equipment'.

when accessing my database:

```
var exercises = await _context.Exercises.ToListAsync();
```

Here is my entity object:

```
public sealed class Exercise
{
    public required int Id { get; set; }
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public string? Instructions { get; set; }
    public required Level Level { get; set; }
    public required WorkoutEquipment Equipment { get; set; }
}
```

Now what puzzles me is that I actually have another enumeration value, "Level", and I don't get an error for that. The only difference I see is one of the properties name matches the Enum type, and the other doesn't. So I have played around both these enums and what happens is:

```
public required Level WorkoutLevel { get; set; } // throws exception
public required WorkoutEquipment Equipment { get; set; } // throws exception

public required Level Level { get; set; } // OK -> changes on the name has an impact
public required WorkoutEquipment WorkoutEquipment {get; set;} // throws exception
```

I have watched several tutorials and read information but I can't understand what I do wrong here as this seems like a pretty basic use case, any input would be greatly appreciated.

Snapshot BuildModel override:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity("BoxingTimer.API.Data.Exercise", b =>
        {
            b.Property<int>("Id")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .HasColumnType("int");

            SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"));

            b.Property<string>("Instructions")
                .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

            b.Property<int>("Level")
                .HasColumnType("int");

            b.Property<string>("Name")
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

            b.Property<int>("WorkoutEquipment")
                .HasColumnType("int");

            b.HasKey("Id");

            b.ToTable("Exercises");
        });
```

Initial migration Up override:

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Exercises",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                Instructions = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Level = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                WorkoutEquipment = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Exercises", x => x.Id);
            });
```

My enum definitions:

```
public enum Level
{
    Undefined,
    Beginner,
    Intermediate,
    Advanced
}

public enum WorkoutEquipment
{
    None,
    Dumbbell,
    JumpRope,
    HeavyBag,
    Cones,
    AgilityLadder
}
```

Comment: Looks like a mismatch with the column name as `WorkoutEquipment`, but the `Exercise` class has property named `Equipment`.